# Values of parameter $a$ for which the inequality $a\cdot9^x+4(a-1)3^x+a>1$ holds

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> The values of parameter $a$ for which the inequality $a\cdot9^x+4(a-1)3^x+a>1$ holds

$\bf{My\; Try::}$ We can write it as $$a\cdot 9^x+4(a-1)3^x+(a-1)>0\Rightarrow a>\frac{4\cdot 3^x+1}{9^x+4\cdot 3^x+1}$$

So we get $$a>\frac{1}{\frac{9^x}{4\cdot 3^x+1}+1}$$

Now $\displaystyle \frac{9^x}{4\cdot 3^x+1} = \frac{1}{16}\left(\frac{16\cdot 9^x-1+1 }{4\cdot 3^x+1}\right) = \frac{1}{16}\left[4\cdot 3^x-1+\frac{1}{4\cdot 3^x+1}\right]$

Now how can i solve it , Help required, Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

put $3^x=y>0$

we want to have

$ay^2+4(a-1)y+(a-1)>0$

if $a=0$ it becomes $-4y-1>0$ which is impossible . we will assume $a\neq 0$.

THERE ARE THREE CASES

the reduced  discriminant must be negative as there is no root.

$\delta <0 \implies$

$(a-1)(4(a-1)-a)<0 \implies$

$(a-1)(3a-4)<0) \implies$

$1<a<\frac{4}{3}$.

we check easily, the polynom is strictly positive.

SECOND CASE

The discriminant is zero and the root is negative.

this gives

$a=1$ and $y=0$

or
$a=\frac{4}{3}$ and $y=-\frac{1}{2}$.

THIRD CASE

The discriminant is strictly positive and the roots are negative.
thus

$\delta=(a-1)(3a-4)>0$

$y_1y_2=\frac{a-1}{a}>0$

and

$y_1+y_2=2\frac{1-a}{a}<0$

which yields to

$a<1 $ and $a>\frac{4}{3}$.

to conclude

if $a\notin [0,1)$ then

$\forall x \in \mathbb R $

$$a9^x+4(a-2)3^x+a-1>0$$

Answer (score 1):

The inequality is
$a \cdot 9^x+4(a-1)3^x+a>1 \Longleftrightarrow \dfrac{4 \cdot 3^x+1}{9^x + 4 \cdot 3^x+1} \Longleftrightarrow a>\dfrac{1}{\dfrac{ 9^x}{4 \cdot 3^x+1}+1 }$

and $\dfrac{ 9^x}{4 \cdot 3^x+1} = \dfrac{9^x+\frac{3^x}{4}-\frac{3^x}{4}}{4\cdot 3^x+1} = \dfrac{3^x}{4}-\dfrac{3^x}{16\cdot 3^x+4}$ is strictly increasing function.

and $\lim_{x \to \infty}\dfrac{ 9^x}{4 \cdot 3^x+1}=\infty$ and $\lim_{x \to -\infty}\dfrac{ 9^x}{4 \cdot 3^x+1}=0$.

So the RHS follows
$0<\dfrac{1}{\dfrac{ 9^x}{4 \cdot 3^x+1}+1 }<1$

Thus such $a$ has to satisfy $a \ge 1$